# Problem with screenlets and permissions?

Tags: permissions, screenlets

I can't get screenlets to open. I've newly installed it on 11.04. Clicking the icon in the applications menu doesn't do anything. I'm on an Acer 4810T timeline laptop.

Here is the terminal output when I run `screenlets-manager`:

```
True
Create autostarter for: Screenlets Daemon
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/screenlets-manager/screenlets-manager.py", line 1332, in <module>
    app = ScreenletsManager()
  File "/usr/share/screenlets-manager/screenlets-manager.py", line 103, in __init__
    utils.lookup_daemon_autostart()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/screenlets/utils.py", line 604, in lookup_daemon_autostart
    f = open(starter, 'w')
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/seamus/.config/autostart/Screenlets Daemon.desktop'
```

When I run `sudo screenlets-manager` I get something about most things being disabled because I'm running as root. I guess the problem is that screenlets needs access to stuff that a normal user doesn't have? Can I get around this?

There is no file `Screenlets Daemon.desktop` in `/home/seamus/.config/autostart/`. Nor is there one in `/usr/share/applications` although there is a `screenlets-manager.desktop` there...

Comment: I think screenlets will not work at 11.04, especially on Unity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to make sure *all* files and directory under you home belong to you. Run this command

```
find ~ ! -user $USER -o ! -group $USER
```

to check this. This other command to repair

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~
```

Then retry `screenlets-manager`. If you have the same result, post the output of

```
ls -ld ~/ ~/.config/ ~/.config/autostart/
```

As a note, never use `sudo` when it is not required.